# Apache (by WHM) Changing MaxRequestWorkers to 20000 still not allowing more than 20 connections without queueing

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm

I have a server running CentOS 7.1 with WHM/Cpanel with 16GB, 8 CPU processors, and I've been having problem with multiple accesses concurrent, it seems it is not allowing, this is the Apache Configuration I set on Apache through the WHM (and right after, restarted apache).
[image: Screenshot from the WHM Configuration]

The configuration is set correctly, but it still doesn't allow more than 20 multiple connections, I'm running a simple PHP script for testing.

test.php

```
<?php sleep(100); ?>
```

And then I run in the browser 20 tabs of this same page, so it keeps connected running multiple instances.

And then I run the page
simple.php on a browser in another computer using another internet connection

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

And it hangs on a lot to load the page (it is probably waiting in a queue, instead of just running), and when I close 10 of the tabs of the test.php page, the simple.php runs instantly as it should, but if I reopen 10 tabs of the test.php, same thing happens, the simple.php takes a lot of time to load.

My server gets a lot of access but it gets so slow to load the pages when I'm having multiple accesses. (even with plenty memory free and CPU Usage percentage very low).

What should I do to allow more connections without apache queuing the HTTP PHP Requests?

Comment: What operating system are you runing on the server

Comment: It's running CentOS 7.1

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to modify the PHP-FPM Pool Options -> Max Requests (which default is 20) under PHP Multi Manager

[image]